# Is it fair to rescale my data here?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, variance, t-test, biostatistics, pre-post-comparison

**Sampling Scenario**

I went out in the field and got 50 baby individuals. By their nature (and not due to a treatment), 25 of them belong to the category `A` and 25 of them belong to the category `B`.

**Goal of the study**

I am interested at the relationship between the category and the adult size of the individuals. As I sampled babies, I will need to let them grow for some arbitrary amount of time in the lab to measure their adult size. I also measure their size at the moment of the sample just in case!

**Data**

Here are some dummy data in `R`

```
require(ggplot2)
set.seed(14)

d = data.frame(
    size = c(rnorm(25,1e3,500), rnorm(25,1e3,400), rnorm(25,5e3,3), rnorm(25,5e3-500,3)),
    time = c(rep("before", 50), rep("after", 50)),
    category = rep(rep(LETTERS[1:2], each=25),2),
    id = rep(1:50,2)
)
d$time = factor(d$time, levels=levels(d$time)[2:1])
dafter = subset(d, time=="after")
dbefore = subset(d, time=="before")
```

**Data Analysis**

Here is a plot of their adult size per category!

```
ggplot(dafter, aes(y=size,x=time, color=category)) + geom_point() + theme_classic()
```

[image: plot of their adult size per category]

And here is a t-test!

```
t.test(data=dafter, size~category)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  size by category
t = 620.6, df = 46.642, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 497.8987 501.1378
sample estimates:
mean in group A mean in group B 
       4999.769        4500.251
```

Great! Exactly what I hypothesized! The effect could not have been more obvious! However, all of a sudden, I realize two things

1. I let them grow for a completely arbitrary amount of time and I cannot argue that they have reached their final size (of even if there exist such thing as a final size)
2. It is very possible that my sample was biased. I might have sampled smaller individuals of category 1 than those of category 2. Not because the population of category 1 and 2 differ in average size when they are baby but only because my sampling method may not have been ideal! Maybe the individuals of category 2 that I sampled were actually a bit older. I can't tell.

I think that I should therefore investigate whether the difference in size observed at adult age is not just a consequence of their size difference at the moment of the sampling. Let's see their size before and after:

```
ggplot(d, aes(y=size,x=time, color=category)) + geom_point() + geom_line(aes(group=id)) + theme_classic()
```

[image: their size before and after]

Let's test if their size differed before

```
t.test(data=dbefore, size~category)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  size by category
t = 2.7186, df = 45.646, p-value = 0.009238
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
  79.19376 531.35144
sample estimates:
mean in group A mean in group B 
       1260.241         954.968
```

Ouch ... there is a significant difference indeed.  I should probably compute the difference in size before and after the growth.

```
ddiff = dafter
ddiff$diffSize = dafter$size - dbefore$size
t.test(data=ddiff, diffSize~category)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  diffSize by category
t = 1.7336, df = 45.644, p-value = 0.08974
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -31.42076 420.90597
sample estimates:
mean in group A mean in group B 
       3739.414        3544.671
```

Not significant. It would be quite unintuitive to conclude that the category does not affect the size (or the growth). I think I am losing a lot of power because the variance among babies is so high. How about if I rescale my data

```
// Please pay attention to how I rescaled them as it may differ from what I should be doing    
ddiff$diffScaledSize = scale(dafter$size) - scale(dbefore$size)
```

and rerun the t-test

```
t.test(data=ddiff, diffScaledSize~category)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  diffScaledSize by category
t = 4.7205, df = 45.643, p-value = 2.262e-05
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.720640 1.792527
sample estimates:
mean in group A mean in group B 
      0.6282917      -0.6282917
```

Looks better to me! However, I am not sure if it is really fair to rescale the size before and after. Is it? How else should I analyse these data?